# Failed to create Jekyll project on macOS Catalina

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I've tried this on macOS Catalina:

```sh
jekyll new qpydown
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    21: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    20: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    19: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.1.0/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
    ...
     2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.13.0/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
     1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': dlopen(/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.13.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.6.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.13.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.13.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle
```

ruby:

```
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin19]
```

I'm new to ruby, I just want to create a github page with jekyll.

Comment: Looks like you installed Ruby with brew. I recommend you install Ruby using a manager like RVM or rbenv: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.7`. Then `gem install jekyll`, then retry your `jekyll new` command.